# How to use PickerView control in MonoDevelop (iPhone)

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Hi, I'm new to iPhone development. I'm working on a PickerView control and I'm facing a problem.
How do I bind a PickerView control with a string array. It takes a `NSObject` as the Datasource property. I have an array of items which I want to bind with this PickerView control but I can't.

I've tried this :

```
String[] item = {"New York", "Toronto", "California"};

pickView.Datasource = (NSObject) item;
```

but it's not working. Please can anyone tell me how I bind a string array with a PickerView control. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Note: any help in Objective C is also accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things work differently on iOS. To provide data to a picker view, you need to create a class that inherits the UIPickerViewModel class:

```
public class PickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
```

Inside that class, you need to override some methods so that your data will be displayed:

```
String[] item = {"New York", "Toronto", "California"};
public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
{
    return item[row];
}

public override int GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView picker, int component)
{
    return item.Length;
}
```

You then set a new instance of this class to your picker view's Model property:

```
pickerView.Model = new PickerModel();
```